# Mongoose - How to add extra key to ObjectId referred array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

```
var conversationSchema = new Schema({
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    recipients: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    messages: [ conversationMessageSchema ]
});
mongoose.model('Conversation', conversationSchema);
```

In the above example, how would you add an extra property in the recipients array, for example... status?

I.E. recipients:

```
[{ _id: { 
    type: Schema.ObjectId, 
    ref: 'User'
  }, 
  status { 
    type: String
  } 
}]
```

Like this^ ?

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

You can do like this

```
 var conversationSchema = new Schema({
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    recipients: [
      name:{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,  ref: 'User' },
      status { type: String}
    ],
    messages: [ conversationMessageSchema ]
});
mongoose.model('Conversation', conversationSchema);
```

Comment: Thanks! Except I would perhaps change "name" to "recipient", as to not confuse someone since that key is technically supposed to be referring to an object that holds the specific recipient information.

Comment: It will not work until you make it :
recipients: [
    {  name:{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,  ref: 'User' },
      status { type: String}}
    ],